# MySQL Performance and Memcache

Tags: mysql, jpa, memcached, eclipselink

I have the following (simplified) Mysql Tables:

```
Requests:
    +----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field                | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | ID                   | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
    | UniqueIdentifier     | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | UniversalServiceId   | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
    +----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Observations:

```
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID                  | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Value               | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| RequestId           | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I have indexed UniqueIdentifier, UniversalServiceId and RequestId.

The tables are queried on UniqueIdentifier and UniversalServiceId with a JOIN on RequestId.

The Observation table has many millions of records.  The queries are painfully slow to return and I am wondering if there is anything that I can do to improve performance.  I have just started reading about memcache but it seems that it may be useful only after the first query (which is often the only one) for a particular dataset.

This is they type of query that is being used:

```
select * from Observations where RequestId in (select ID from Requests where UniqueIdentifier = '123456' and UniversalServiceId = '1234'
```

Any advice / guidance appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use a query using a JOIN operation, rather than an `IN (subquery)` predicate.

For example:

```
SELECT o.ID
     , o.Value
     , o.RequestId
  FROM Observations o
  JOIN Requests r
    ON r.ID = o.RequestId
 WHERE r.UniqueIdentifier = '123456' 
   AND r.UniversalServiceId = '1234'
```

For optimum performance, suitable indexes would be:

```
... ON Requests (UniversalServiceId, UniqueIdentifier, ID)
... ON Observations (RequestId, Value, ID)
```

(The choice of the leading column in the index on the Requests table would depend on the expected cardinality.)

Comment: So am I correct in saying that Memcache would have no impact on performance in this case?

Comment: memcached won't do anything to speed up the execution of the database query. But it may improve performance of your application, by storing frequently accessed data in memory, so you don't need to run a database query; that will help with database performance, if you can offload repeated requests for the same information, avoiding unnecessary database queries. But if the database query is slow, I'd address that issue first... use EXPLAIN to show the execution plan; lots of ways to improve MySQL performance, increase InnoDB buffer pool size to reduce i/o waits, use InnoDB not MyISAM, etc.